# Blender 3.5: Archimesh baseboard orientation and autoholes?

Tags: modeling, archimesh-add-on

[image]

So I have made a wall with a certain kind of window and used autoholes. If I attached the wireframe, you would see the hole has been made (plus the glass is transparent to the balcony) yet the baseboard still goes right on through. How do I fix this? Thanks.

In a separate but related issue, I have some walls going around and the baseboard is on the outside but I would like it to be double-faced i.e. facing outside as well, is there some way to increase baseboard thickness or have it go on both sides of the wall?

[image]